# importing tensorpack logger error

Tags: python, tensorflow

importing logger of tensorpack gives following error:

```
>>> from tensorpack import logger
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/wangtao/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorpack/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorpack.dataflow import *
  File "/home/wangtao/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorpack/dataflow/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    _global_import(module_name)
  File "/home/wangtao/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorpack/dataflow/__init__.py", line 14, in _global_import
    p = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), level=1)
  File "/home/wangtao/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorpack/dataflow/parallel.py", line 424, in <module>
    PlasmaPutData = create_dummy_class('PlasmaPutData', 'pyarrow')   # noqa
NameError: name 'create_dummy_class' is not defined
```

someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Authors here. This is a bug (a missing import) that has been fixed after a day. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is lines in the source [tensorpack/tensorpack/dataflow/parallel.](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/blob/6bdd046057e507087f6da3af909d4bcf1726cff2/tensorpack/dataflow/parallel.py#L421-L425)
although I dont know what's the purpose of those lines, but I know I missed the `pyarrow` package, `pip install pyarrow` solved the problem

```
try:
    import pyarrow.plasma as plasma
except ImportError:
    PlasmaPutData = create_dummy_class('PlasmaPutData', 'pyarrow')   # noqa
    PlasmaGetData = create_dummy_class('PlasmaGetData', 'pyarrow')   # noqa
```